# how to concatenate a string and a object together to form one payload

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-component, anypoint-platform

I have requirement where I need to put together a set of string and a object.
Which am trying different ways but unable to do so please help me.
example-
abc
xyz
back space
{
"hello":"world"
}

Comment: What are the inputs and the expected output? What is the type of the expected output?

Comment: I need to concatenate a set of strings and a object Input is- 1st paylod is - {
  "employee": "sara",
  "categories": {
    "id": "employee01",
    "name": "sara"
  }
} 2nd payload is - QU sara
world ***BACF MESSAGE*** I need to add both of  them in one payload and form it in text/plain Please guide me how can i achieve this

Comment: @Auro can you update the explanation from the comment to the question too? It is difficult to understand what you want from the question itself

Comment: @HarshankBansal thank you for response. I received the response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object and a string can not be concatenated together since they are of incompatible types. However you can "print" the object to a string, and then concatenate it.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var payload1={ "employee": "sara", "categories": { "id": "employee01", "name": "sara" } }
var payload2="QU sara world BACF MESSAGE"
---
write(payload1,"application/java") ++ " " ++ payload2
```

Output (of type string): `{employee=sara, categories={id=employee01, name=sara}} QU sara world BACF MESSAGE`

Comment: Thank you so much it resolved my issue like real quick.
From now will always keep in mind how to concatenate different types of payload.

Comment: This is not a method to magically make incompatible types compatible for concatenation, unless you mean as strings. I converted one of the inputs to a string. It may not be appropriate for every conversion. Also the output is always a string. If you need a different output type you need a different method.